# How can I use the root directory of a project as the debug directory in VStudio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, directory, sql-server-ce, root

I'm working on a C# project in VS2010 express using a SQL CE database, when run the database is copied to the debug directory (root\bin\Debug) and that one is used instead. This means when the program runs again, the changes made previously are lost.

I have found that changing the debug directory from "root\bin\Debug" to be in the root that this problem is avoided, however I'm concerned that this may have some unwanted side effects.

Is there a better way of doing this or should this be okay?

Comment: Why do you need to have the DB in the debug directory? Can't you put it anywhere else you'd like and store that path in your config file and reference it that way?

Comment: @BobHorn I'd thought of that but I have the project on a portable USB device so the directory path is not the same on different computers.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the [Copy To Output directory] to Dont copy for the database and interact with the original database itself. In this way, the changes you made wont be lost in next build.

Comment: The only way I see of doing that is by setting the full path to the DB and as I'm working off a USB pen the path isn't always the same.